# How to create padas.DataFrame from list of list of JSON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas DataFrame from CSV ([gist with small sample](https://gist.github.com/feeeper/9c7b1e8f8a4cc262f17675ef0f6e1124)):

```
|  title   |                       genres               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| %title1% |[{id: 1, name: '...'}, {id: 2, name: '...'}]|
| %title2% |[{id: 2, name: '...'}, {id: 4, name: '...'}]|
...
| %title9% |[{id: 3, name: '...'}, {id: 9, name: '...'}]|
```

Each `title` can be associated with a various count of the genres (more or greater 1).

The task is to convert arrays from `genre` column into columns and put ones (or `True`s) for each genre:

```
|  title   | genre_1 | genre_2 | genre_3 | ... | genre_9 |
---------------------------------------------------------
| %title1% |    1    |    1    |    0    | ... |    0    |
| %title2% |    1    |    0    |    0    | ... |    0    |
...
| %title9% |    0    |    0    |    1    | ... |    1    |
```

Genres are the constant set (about 20 items in that set).

Naive method is:

1. Create the set of all genres
2. Create columns for each genre filled with 0
3. For each row, in the DataFrame check if some of the genres are in the `genres` columns and fill the column for that genre with 1.

This approach looks a bit weird.

I think that pandas have a more suitable method for that.

Comment: How did you get to that structure in the first place?

Comment: @roganjosh From CSV file

Comment: CSV files cannot hold python lists and dictionaries. Either that column is a string or you parsed the CSV into that structure

Comment: @roganjosh In CSV this values just strings https://gist.github.com/feeeper/9c7b1e8f8a4cc262f17675ef0f6e1124

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to perform JSON-deserialization on a Pandas dataframe in a vectorized fashion. One way you ought to be able to do this is with [`.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) which will let you do this in one loop (albeit slower than most built-in pandas operations).

```
import json

df = # ... your dataframe

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # deserialize the JSON string
    json_data = json.loads(row['genres'])

    # add a new column for each of the genres (Pandas is okay with it being sparse)
    for genre in json_data:
        df.loc[index, genre['name']] = 1  # update the row in the df itself

df.drop(['genres'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Note that empty cells with be filled with `NaN`, not 0 -- you should use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to change this. A brief example with a vaguely similar dataframe looks like

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'title': 'hello', 'json': '{"foo": "bar"}'}, {'title': 'world', 'json': '{"foo": "bar", "ba
   ...: z": "boo"}'}])

In [3]: df.head()
Out[3]:
                           json  title
0                {"foo": "bar"}  hello
1  {"foo": "bar", "baz": "boo"}  world

In [4]: import json
   ...: for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ...:     data = json.loads(row['json'])
   ...:     for k, v in data.items():
   ...:         df.loc[index, k] = v
   ...: df.drop(['json'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [5]: df.head()
Out[5]:
   title  foo  baz
0  hello  bar  NaN
1  world  bar  boo
```

Comment: I don't think this works? Varying numbers of keys will give you mismatched columns

Comment: I updated the assignment to use `df.loc` instead of `row` (which prevented the changes from being saved to the `df`. Any missing keys end up as `NaN` in the dataframe.

Comment: I tried to find a solution without iteration over all rows

Answer (score 0):

If your csv data looks like this.

*(i added the quotes to the keys of genres json just to work easily with json package. Since it is not the main problem you can do that as preprocessing)*

[image]

You will have to iterate through all the rows of input DataFrame .

```
for index, row in inputDf.iterrows():
    fullDataFrame = pd.concat([fullDataFrame, get_dataframe_for_a_row(row)])
```

in get_dataframe_for_a_row function:

- prepare a DataFrame with column title and value row['title']
- add columns with names formed by appending id to 'genre_'.
- assign them value of 1

and then build a DataFrame for each row and concat them to a full DataFrame .
pd.concat() concatenates the dataframe obtained from each row.
will merge the comumns if already exist.

finally, `fullDataFrame.fillna(0)` to replace NaN with 0

your final DataFrame will look like this. 
 [image]

here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

inputDf = pd.read_csv('title_genre.csv')

def labels_for_genre(a):
    a[0]['id']
    labels = []
    for i in range(0 , len(a)):
        label = 'genre'+'_'+str(a[i]['id'])
        labels.append(label)
    return labels

def get_dataframe_for_a_row(row): 
    labels = labels_for_genre(json.loads(row['genres']))
    tempDf = pd.DataFrame()
    tempDf['title'] = [row['title']]
    for label in labels:
        tempDf[label] = ['1']
    return tempDf

fullDataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in inputDf.iterrows():
    fullDataFrame = pd.concat([fullDataFrame, get_dataframe_for_a_row(row)])
fullDataFrame = fullDataFrame.fillna(0)
```

Comment: I tried to find a solution without iteration over all rows

Answer (score 0):

Full working solution without `iterrows`:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import json

# read data
movies_df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/feeeper/9c7b1e8f8a4cc262f17675ef0f6e1124/raw/022c0d45c660970ca55e889cd763ce37a54cc73b/example.csv', converters={ 'genres': json.loads })

# get genres for all items
all_genres_entries = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(movies_df['genres'].values))

# create the list with unique genres
genres = list({v['id']:v for v in all_genres_entries}.values())

# fill genres columns
for genre in genres:
    movies_df['genre_{}'.format(genre['id'])] = movies_df['genres'].apply(lambda x: 1 if genre in x else 0)
```

Comment: Yes, you are still iterating through the 'genres'. The point of using iterrows was to include the title also. I think you needed title also in the output dataframe.

Comment: @darshanz As you can see I didn't create new dataframe - just added new columns (one per genre). So I still have titles in the dataframe.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you were writing to same dataframe. But your solution still fails. So did the one you had earlier when you didn't use itertools.

Comment: Please check your last line. It will fail unless you have all distinct genre_id throughout the dataset.

Comment: @darshanz Sorry, but I can't understand why should it fail. `genres` list has all genres that can be found in the dataset.